# Why can't I use String.format() to format a string that came from Integer.toBinaryString()?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

`inttime[]` is an array that already holds single-digit integer values. The first `for` loop seeks to convert each integer to a binary string and store it to the string array `bintime[]`. This part works fine, but when I try to run the next for loop, I get an illegal format conversion error.

```
for(int j = 0; j < inttime.length; j++){
bintime[j] = Integer.toBinaryString(inttime[j]);
}

for(int a = 0; a < bintime.length; a++){
System.out.println(String.format("%04d",bintime[a]));
}
```

Why is this happening if `bintime[]` is a `String` array?

Comment: `%04d` expects an integer (hence `d`). Use `%04s`.

Comment: Your question answers your question--why can't you format strings as numbers? Because they're strings.

Comment: You can use System.out.format as a shortcut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `bintime` array holds `Strings` - as you've stated and you're assigning to the array from `Integer.toBinaryString` - you'll see an exception from `format` trying to print the `String` as `int`: the `%d` format expects an `int`, and not a `String`.

If you're trying to pad the `String` representation of a base 2 number, then use something like:

```
System.out.println(
  String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(inttime[idx])).replace(' ', '0'));
```

The `4` in the format string represents the *minimum* width of the `String`, shorter strings will be padded with spaces.

Comment: No point in inferring, he states it at the end of his post :-p

Comment: I'm trying to add leading zeros to each binary number

Comment: @user1604288 see edit: you'll need to use `String` manipulation to pad out the binary string